# Convexity proof - can I get some pointers?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Prove that $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is convex iff $\forall m \in \mathbb{N}$ and every set of $m$ points $\{x_1,...,x_m\} \subset C$ we have that $\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i x_i \in C$

Where $\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i = 1$ and $\lambda_i \geq 0 $ for all $i=1,...,m$.

My attempt at this deviously straightforward question:

Assume that $\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i x_i \in C$ then for any two points $x_a,x_b \in C$
$$\lambda_a x_a + \lambda_b x_b \in C$$

Since $\lambda_i \geq 0$ then for convexity 
$\{\lambda x_a + (1-\lambda)x_b\} 0 \leq \lambda \leq 1\}$
is satisfied (have I shown sufficient proof of this?)

Conversely assume $\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i x_i \notin C$

Then there exists two points $x_\alpha , x_\beta$ such that 
$\lambda_\alpha x_\alpha + \lambda_\beta x_\beta \notin C$

Hence there exists some $\lambda$ such that $\lambda x_\alpha + (1-\lambda)x_\beta \notin C$ for $0 \leq \lambda \leq 1$ and therefore $C$ is not convex.

Can anyone give me pointers on how to improve my attempt (if it needs any) or where I've made any logical fallacies (if I have).

Regards,
~e

Comment: I don't understand *at all* your first part "proof": you **must** show that $\;x,y\in C\implies tx+(1-t)y\in C\;$ , too...what are those weird $\;\lambda_a\,,\,\lambda_b\;$ ? Same thing for second part...

Comment: Upon reflection it was an entirely trivial statement to make.

I was just saying that there would exist some $\lambda$s associated with those $x_a, x_b$ such that the sum of those terms would be in $C$ as implied by the assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\;C\;$ is convex and let $\;x_1,...,x_n\in C\;$ . Proceed inductively: for $\;n=2\;$ it is exactly the definition of convexity, so assume for $\;n-1\;$ and prove for $\;n\;$ : let $\;\lambda_i\ge 0\;$ be such that $\;\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\lambda_k=1\;$ .The induction hypothesis gives us that

$$\sum_{k=2}^n\left(\frac{\lambda_k}{\sum\limits_{i=2}^n\lambda_i}\right)x_k= c\in C$$

Check the above *carefully*! Get convinced that the sum of those coefficients indeed is $\;1\;$ ...and check the following *slowly*:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_kx_k=\lambda_1x_1+\sum_{k=2}^n\lambda_k\left[\sum_{k=2}^n\left(\frac{\lambda_k}{\sum\limits_{i=2}^n\lambda_i}\right)x_k\right]=\lambda_1x_1+c\sum_{k=2}^n\lambda_k=$$

$$=\lambda_1x_1+(1-\lambda_1)c\in C$$

and we're done.

The other direction, particularly once the above is properly understood, is almost trivial.